# ENOTFOUND when extending mysql docker image

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I created the following dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:8.0
CMD ["mysqld", "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
```

However when I try to connect to it after running, i get the following in my node application

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mysql mysql:3306

Am I doing something wrong in my dockerfile? I just want to always add that argument when running that image. Using Gitlab CI which doesnt support passing command arguments through its interface nor can I directly use the `docker run` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem, was related to gitlab CI and not docker.

I tagged my image as `mysql-native-auth` which means in gitlab CI when specifying the host to connect to, you must use `mysql-native-auth` and not `mysql`, as apparently the service's image name is what determines this (unless you specify an alias)

Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services

> ```
> services:
> - tutum/wordpress:latest
> ```
>
> If you don't specify a service alias, when the job is run, tutum/wordpress will be started and you will have access to it from your build container under two hostnames to choose from:
>
> - tutum-wordpress
> - tutum__wordpress